# Dlib gathering points with glob

Tags: python, points, dib

I am new in python and nowadays I am trying work with gathering coordinates of points with dlib C++ library. But I cannot understand this code. Please help me

```
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.JPG")):
    fh = open(f + ".txt","w")

    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = io.imread(f)
```

Comment: for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.JPG")):
    fh = open(f + ".txt","w")
    
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = io.imread(f)

Comment: for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.JPG")):
    fh = open(f + ".txt","w")
    
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = io.imread(f)